# Swiftで複数のクラスで使う関数を定義したい場合、その定義はどこに書けばいいのですか？

Tags: swift, xcode

```
func imageForItem(item: Item) -> UIImage {
            var image : UIImage!

    //...

            return image
        }
```

例えば上の関数みたいなものを
複数のクラスから参照したい場合、どこに定義すればよいですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

特に決まりはありません。私の知る限り「これが定番」と言えるほど一般化したやり方もありません。グローバルな関数定義を書くための.swiftファイルを作って(もちろんプロジェクトに追加して)そこに記載すれば、同じプロジェクト内のどのファイルからでも参照できます。(他のファイルを間借り、例えばItem.swiftのクラス定義の後に追加してもOkです。)

---

もし一つだけ、かなり一般化しつつある指針があるとしたら、「できるだけグローバルな関数定義は行わない」と言うことでしょうか。

あなたが例としてあげられたコードであれば、`Item`クラスのextensionとして書くことができます。

```
//Item+image.swift
extension Item {
    var image: UIImage {
        var resultImage: UIImage!
        //...関数の`item`引数の代わりに`self`を使って記述
        return resultImage
    }
}
```

と言った感じのextensionを作ってやれば、`imageForItem(anItem)`の代わりに`anItem.image`で同じ結果が得られるようになります。
　ちなみにこのようなextensionを`Item`クラスとは別のファイルに置くのであれば、Appleのサンプルコードでは、"{元のクラス名}+{拡張を表す簡単な単語}.swift"と言ったファイル名にすることが多いです。

あげられた例は単純化してあって、やはりメソッドにはしにくいものもあるかも知れませんが、「関数よりもextension」はSwiftでプログラミングするなら一度は検討された方が良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。かなりスッキリしますね！言語を学ぶことは開発効率の改善に大きく影響すると実感しました。ちなみにItemに関するその他の変数（例えばsizeとか）を定義したい場合、このSwiftファイルの中に追加して書くのが一般的でしょうか？

Comment: 残念ながらストア型プロパティはextensionには書けません。ストア型プロパティ以外でもクラスの動作やデータ構造に関わる基本的なことはクラス定義と切り離さずに書いた方が良いでしょう。プロトコルと組み合わせると、共通に「基本的なこと」を持っている複数のクラス（や構造体）に同時にextensionを定義できたりします。どういった機能単位でまとめると綺麗なコードになるか、学習しながら試していってください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。勉強していきます。